# Create new home site and demote current to a subsite

Tags: site, infrastructure

I am using Sharepoint 2010 foundation. I started by creating several sites from a main site. Call It technicalhome. I now have to demote this home so I can now have finance home, HRhome etc all sites currently below the Technical home would be subsite of that site. Is this possible will it change the functioning of the current subsites?

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable by simply changing the URL of the sites under 'Look and Feel' in Site Settings. Changing the URL of the site will 're-parent' it, and you can set another site to be the root site of the site collection.

Comment: So it should not break all the links to the current main site? I can then have a new top layer with a new top site.